# Concatenate count variable and string in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, concatenation

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
age = ['1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '2', '3', '2', '1']
list_of_tuples = list(zip(name, age))
list_of_tuples
count = []
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns=['name', 'age'])
df['count'] = (df.groupby(['age']).cumcount() + 1)
print(df)
```

the current output is this:

```
  name age  count
0    a   1      1
1    b   1      2
2    c   2      1
3    d   1      3
4    e   3      1
5    f   2      2
6    g   3      2
7    h   2      3
8    i   1      4
```

But i need output like below

```
   name  age   count
0    a   1      cat_1
1    b   1      cat_2
2    c   2      rat_1
3    d   1      cat_3
4    e   3      mat_1
5    f   2      rat_2
6    g   3      mat_2
7    h   2      rat_3
8    i   1      cat_4
```

Can anyone help me how to do?
And explain how you solved it?

Comment: Please show as an example correct output (not just the output your code currently gives).

Comment: @KentShikama i modified. please check out.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why is row 3, `ab_3` as opposed to `cd_3`?

Comment: @KentShikama that has nothing to do with the name field given there. It can be any string in the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary and add counts converted to strings:

```
d = {'1':'cat', '2':'rat', '3':'mat'}
#if numbers are integers
#d = {1:'cat', 2:'rat', 3:'mat'}
df['count'] = df['age'].map(d) + '_' +(df.groupby(['age']).cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

print (df)
  name age  count
0    a   1  cat_1
1    b   1  cat_2
2    c   2  rat_1
3    d   1  cat_3
4    e   3  mat_1
5    f   2  rat_2
6    g   3  mat_2
7    h   2  rat_3
8    i   1  cat_4
```